# OpenErp facing TypeError: ClientWidget is null

Tags: centos, odoo

I encounter error "TypeError: ClientWidget is null" / "TypeError: this.user_context is undefined" when login to openerp or clicking on app, settings menu.

I have updated the fix on my code i found on this issue https://code.launchpad.net/~openerp-dev/openerp-web/7.0-bug-1095919-psa/+merge/142092 . but still its not resolved...
I have restarted server after updating files. but still facing same error.

kindly suggest me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just avoid clicking on "Apps" menu, instead of that click on "Installed Modules" menu. Update your openerp instance, now it's fixed.

Comment: Hi Parthiv, thanks for your answer, could you describe it in detail, how to update instance, i did not get you. Kindly share links or docs..

Answer (score 0):

"TypeError: ClientWidget is null" often occurs after uninstallation of some modules/addons.
A temporary fix is re-installing them.

1. Login then **right-click** on any of the top level menus (eg. setting) and **open in a new tab**.
2. Re-install the module

Other good tips can be found at the following link:
http://help.openerp.com/question/8763/removing-social-networks-module-screws-up-system/